# Website shortcuts by name in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, mac, shortcuts

Is it possible to configure e.g. I type "stackoverflow" in the website bar and just hit enter and instead of it google searching it would go directly to stackoverflow? Or so that I can connect any alias to a website of my choosing?

Comment: Isn't this default behaviour? If I type stackoverflow, it'll automatically complete the address to the full website. Not sure about defining your own aliases though.

Comment: For me it takes me to the most frequently visited subpage/article of stackoverflow, so I always end up going there, and it keeps being the most frequently visited one for this reason :D and yes the aliasing would be ideal, since I would want to go to different subpages with different alias. i.e. prod to go to github.com/prod and master to go to github.com/master for example

Answer (score 0):

You could consider an alternate route: I have a bookmarks bar (turn on with **COMMAND+SHIFT+B**) that contains the front pages of my most visited websites. If you remove the title text in the shortcut, all you see in the bar is the icon. That way you can wedge in dozens and dozens of websites at a single click.

Add bookmark (COMMAND+D), delete title:

[image: chrome bookmarks bar, add]

Results in this (the three icons at the bottom are part of the bookmarks bar):

[image: chrome bookmarks bar]

If you COMMAND-click any of these, they will open in a new tab without a preceding blank page (so using BACK means you end up at the front page of the new website, rather than that blank page).